# trying to use exact=TRUE feature in R glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to use exact=TRUE feature in glmnet. But I am getting an error message.

```
> fit = glmnet(as.matrix(((x_values))), (as.matrix(y_values)),penalty=variable.list$penalty)
> coef.exact = coef(fit, s = 0.03, exact = TRUE)
Error: used coef.glmnet() or predict.glmnet() with `exact=TRUE` so must in addition supply original argument(s)  x and y and penalty.factor  in order to safely rerun glmnet
```

How can I supply penalty.factor to coef.exact?

Options tried:-

```
> coef.exact = coef(as.matrix(((x_values))), (as.matrix(y_values)),penalty=variable.list$penalty, s = 0.03, exact = TRUE)
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> 
> coef.exact = coef((as.matrix(((x_values))), (as.matrix(y_values)),penalty=variable.list$penalty), s = 0.03, exact = TRUE)
Error: unexpected ',' in "coef.exact = coef((as.matrix(((x_values))),"
> 
> coef.exact = coef((as.matrix(((x_values))) (as.matrix(y_values)) penalty=variable.list$penalty), s = 0.03, exact = TRUE)
Error: unexpected symbol in "coef.exact = coef((as.matrix(((x_values))) (as.matrix(y_values)) penalty"
> 
> coef.exact = coef(fit(as.matrix(((x_values))), (as.matrix(y_values)),penalty=variable.list$penalty), s = 0.03, exact = TRUE)
Error in fit(as.matrix(((x_values))), (as.matrix(y_values)), penalty = variable.list$penalty) : 
  could not find function "fit"
> 
> coef.exact = coef(glmnet(as.matrix(((x_values))), (as.matrix(y_values)),penalty=variable.list$penalty), s = 0.03, exact = TRUE)
Error: used coef.glmnet() or predict.glmnet() with `exact=TRUE` so must in addition supply original argument(s)  x and y and penalty.factor  in order to safely rerun glmnet
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `mtcars` as sample data. Note it's always advisable to provide a [minimal & reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including sample data when posting on SO.

```
# Fit mpg ~ wt + disp
x <- as.matrix(mtcars[c("wt", "disp")]);
y <- mtcars[, "mpg"];
fit <- glmnet(x, y, penalty = 0.1); 

# s is our regularisation parameter, and since we want exact results
# for s=0.035, we need to refit the model using the full data (x,y)
coef.exact <- coef(fit, s = 0.035, exact = TRUE, x = x, y = y, penalty.factor = 0.1);
coef.exact;
#3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                      1
#(Intercept) 34.40289989
#wt          -3.00225110
#disp        -0.02016836
```

The reason why you explicitly need to provide `x` and `y` again is given in `?coef.glmnet` (also see @FelipeAlvarenga post).

---

So in your case, the following should work:

```
fit = glmnet(x = as.matrix(x_values), y = y_values, penalty=variable.list$penalty)
coef.exact = coef(
    fit, 
    s = 0.03, 
    exact = TRUE, 
    x = as.matrix(x_values), 
    y = y_values, 
    penalty.factor = variable.list$penalty)
```

---

### Some comments

Perhaps the confusion arises from the difference between the model's overall regularisaton parameter (`s` or lambda) and the `penalty.factor`s that you can apply to every coefficient. The latter allows for differential regularisation of individual parameters, whereas `s` controls the effect of overall L1/L2 regularisation.

Answer (score 0):

In `coef` the parameter `s` corresponds to the penalty parameter. In the help files:

> s  Value(s) of the penalty parameter lambda at which predictions are
>   required. Default is the entire sequence used to create the model.

[...]

> With exact=TRUE, these different values of s are merged (and sorted)
>   with object$lambda, and the model is refit before predictions are
>   made. In this case, it is required to supply the original data x= and
>   y= as additional named arguments to predict() or coef(). The workhorse
>   predict.glmnet() needs to update the model, and so needs the data used
>   to create it. The same is true of weights, offset, penalty.factor,
>   lower.limits, upper.limits if these were used in the original call.
>   Failure to do so will result in an error.

Therefore, to use `exact = T` you must assign your original penalties, x, y and any other parameter you inputted in your original model

Comment: that part I got it but how exactly penalty is to be supplied. I tried couple of ways but none seems to be working so far.